# Three factor user authentication for a web application using WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We have a requirement in one of our projects where our client wants 3 factor authentication for a web application.
We are already using WSO2 IS for user authentication and authorization.
We would like to know if WSO2 IS supports 3 factor authentication of web application users.

Following is the requirement of 3 factor authentication
Factor #1- Username and password
Factor #2 – Individual/Personal digital certificate
Factor #3 – Biometric of the user

Can WSO2 team let us know if this 3 factor authentication is possible using WSO2 IS so that we can approach them for more details.
It would be great if we get any reference link to some doc so that we can share it with our management for further decision.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Identity Server supports multi-factor authentication with any number of steps. Refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider) documentation for more information.

In your authentication flow, you need 3 specific authenticators. WSO2 Identity Server supports basic authentication. But other 2 authenticators are not supported out of the box. But you can download the relevant authenticators from the connector store and deploy.

For certificate based authentication, you can find the connector from [here](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/59dd58ed-8335-476e-8ff6-069fc3620104) and documentation from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+X509Certificate+Authenticator).

For bio-metric authentication we do have one connector. You can find the connector from [here](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/00902cc7-5efc-4b8f-aae7-930e999f8058) and documentation from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+MePIN+Authenticator). If you need any other bio-metric authenticator, please refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Writing+a+Custom+Federated+Authenticator) documentation to write your own authenticator.